# How to block a piece of code for multiple processes

Tags: php, mysql

As I have installed cron run the same script every minute. At the same time a script is executed several times.

There is such a part:

```
$query = mysql_query("select distinct `task_id` from tasks_pending where `checked`='0' and `taken`='0' limit 50");
```

Then, the obtained values ​​set "taken = 1"

Since several processes are executed at the same time the request Return the same data for different processes. Is it possible to somehow disable this part of her time to can perform only one process?

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: [`LOCK TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html)

Comment: I'd better use transactions and blocks, so that only one process could have an access to database table at a time. The other way is to have one "main" script that would have all the data and then give pieces to others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SELECT FOR UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) and it will block another process to select the same rows, before they are updated

Comment: Neat, I didn't even know you could do this, I have always locked the whole table. +1

Answer (score 1):

You might want to lock the table before doing anything with it, and unlock it afterwards using the `[UN]LOCK TABLES` statements.

Otherwise, you could use a `SELECT FOR UPDATE` query within a transaction scope.